# Checking NVRAM on BootUp

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader, reboot, cmos

I've recently encountered with my desktop the other day. the problems were like this

- Computer boots up. and Shows this Message

> F1 for Setup and  Configuration
>    F2 to load default values
>   Checking NVRAM

Once select F2 my computer boots up normaly.

this always happen when I bootup my computer

but upon bootup my time and date settings are incorrect, even if I change them. once I shutdown my PC.  they will change again.

am I having CMOS problems? or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it seems like your CMOS battery is starting to die (because of the problem of not being able to permanently reset the time and date in the BIOS).

Before you change the CMOS battery, you should write down all of your current BIOS settings. If you change the CMOS battery, all of your BIOS settings will be reset to their defaults.

Before going to get a new CMOS battery, remove the CMOS battery so that you can read the engraved battery model number on the top side of the battery. Take the old battery with you when you buy a new one to make sure that the new battery is the same size and model number as the old one.

[image: CMOS battery]

Comment: what type of battery should I get? my motherboard is a ASUS p7h55 motherboard.

Comment: The best thing to do is to remove the CMOS battery so that you can read the engraved battery model number on the top side of the battery. Also you should take the battery with you when you buy a new one to make sure that the new battery is the same size and model number as the old one.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like your CMOS battery in your PC is failing.  This is easy to fix.  Open up your computer and find the battery.  It looks like the picture below:

[image: CMOS battery]

If the CR# is visible, just write it down.  If not, you can gently remove the battery with a small screwdriver and it will be written on one of the sided.  Also, make a note of which side is positive (+) so you can be sure to put the battery in the correct way once you have the CR#.

CR#'s are standardized, so any brand that matches that number will be the right size and voltage.  Once you have the proper CR# you can order a new one online, or go to your local RadioShack, or equivalent.

You do not have to worry about losing your settings like another poster answered.  CMOS will retain its setting for about 10-15 minutes after the battery is removed.  So after you have your new battery, just pry the old one out and put the new one in (again make sure you put it in the right way).

Answer (score 0):

In BIOS, go to "PCI/PnP Configuration"-> change "Clear NVRAM" from "No" to "YES".

This problem annoyed me for half a year. One of my Lecroy LABMASTER oscillscope always stucks here. AND the side effect is that the WIN7 will corrupt if this stuck occur, leaving a system recovery must needed else cannot enter the system.

The specification of the motherboard I found is this. https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/5500/MNL-1083.pdf

By searching "NVRAM", I found this solution.

Hope it can help.

This problem is similar with
[Boot stuck on checking NVRAM on bios](https://superuser.com/questions/1370463/boot-stuck-on-checking-nvram-on-bios/1831428#1831428)