# Boot stuck on checking NVRAM on bios

Tags: boot, bios

Whlist I have been booting my computer that has been sitting over 2-3 years I noticed that the boot process stopped on the following message

```
Checking NVRAM
```

And did not proceed any further to boot the os.
Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: My first thought on seeing the title was "CMOS battery". Usually a small flathead screwdriver can be used to release the catch holding it in.

Comment: Well that actually was the answer as you can see  bellow, I also tell and the type of battery used + tips on how to obdain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/594147/checking-nvram-on-bootup) the clock battery (a small round shiny part to the motherboard) seems to have died.

The fix is easy just by bying a new one, the type of battery usually used is a `CR-2032` `button cell` ( use keyword `CR-2032 battery` when searching on ebay,amazon etc etc) one usually found in clocks and small devices.

You can use a small toothpick or a small flat-head screwdriver or any tool using small pointing arrow to remove the old one, then just place the new one in a same manner that old one has been placed (usually the side with `+` icon looking upwards)

Also in Greece you can find this type of battery on computer stores, e-shop (the brand of a Hellenic eshop) or even to street vendors at flea market (aka Laiki) as well at the stalls selling tools,cables,knives etc etc. If the battery is obtained from flea market, remove it first and show it to the owner of the stall, the owner will provide you the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

In BIOS, go to "PCI/PnP Configuration"-> change "Clear NVRAM" from "No" to "YES".

This problem annoyed me for half a year.
One of my Lecroy LABMASTER oscillscope always stucks here. AND the side effect is that the WIN7 will corrupt if this stuck occur, leaving a system recovery must needed else cannot enter the system.

The specification of the motherboard I found is this.
https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/5500/MNL-1083.pdf

By searching "NVRAM", I found this solution.

Hope it can help.